# Vaadin - Get the currently shown Notification from a Window

Tags: java, vaadin

Is it possible to somehow get the currently shown [Notification](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Window.Notification.html) from a given window in Vaadin? [Looking at the Window API](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Window.html), all I can see is a couple of `showWindow()` methods.

**So, does anyone know if there exist some functionality for getting the currently shown [Notification](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Window.Notification.html) (if there is any Notification present, that is)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe there is currently any way to do this.

You could override Window#showNotification(Notification) to keep track of this yourself, but as far as I can see, the client doesn't tell the server that the notification has been closed => there's no way of "resetting" this flag.

(the private method Window#addNotification keeps track of the notifications to send to the browser in a linked list, but Window#paintContent(PaintTarget) clears that list as soon as they are sent to the browser)

Comment: I was just about to answer the same :) @Andiaz could maybe use the [`getDelayMsec()`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Window.Notification.html#getDelayMsec%28%29) method to see if the tracked notifications are still shown.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I didn't consider overriding the showNotification, but that's most likely what I'll do. :)

Answer (score 1):

By reflection :

```
private boolean isNotified(String notif) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException,
IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Page current = Page.getCurrent();

    Field f = current.getClass().getDeclaredField("notifications");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    List<Notification> notifications = (List<Notification>) f.get(current);
    boolean found = false;
    if (notifications != null) {
        for (Notification notification : notifications) {
            if (notification.getCaption() == notif) {
                found=true;
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```